# 3/6 tab html layout, where the tabs occupy the whole width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a "tab widget", and I want the tabs to occupy the whole width of it. If there were 4 or 5 tabs, I could change the width of the li's to 25% or 20% or a definite number, but since I want 6 tabs, the number would have to be 16.66666667%, and it never looks good.

Is there a right way to make this layout so that the tabs occupy the whole screen?+

Current HTML and CSS (jsfiddle at the bottom):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Default Action
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

        //On Click Event
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Seville</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2"></a>Alicante</li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Córdoba</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">San Juan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab6">Havana</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 1</h2>
            <p> Content 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p> Content 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 3</h2>
            <p> Content 3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 4</h2>
            <p> Content 4</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 5</h2>
            <p> Content 5</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab6" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 5</h2>
            <p> Content 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>

.container {
    width: 1300;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.tab_content h3 a {
    color: #254588;
}

.tab_content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Quick jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75fff7vp/

Comment: Maybe you can take a look to http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified and check how they do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox. I just forked your jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/andreasonny83/dgfazh1r/

```css
.container {
    width: 1300;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  display: flex;
}

ul.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 31px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-left: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  display: block;
  flex: auto;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.tab_content h3 a {
    color: #254588;
}

.tab_content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Default Action
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

        //On Click Event
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Seville</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2"></a>Alicante</li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Córdoba</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">San Juan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab6">Havana</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 1</h2>
            <p> Content 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p> Content 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 3</h2>
            <p> Content 3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 4</h2>
            <p> Content 4</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 5</h2>
            <p> Content 5</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab6" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 5</h2>
            <p> Content 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been looking for an opportunity to learn flexbox, this looks like a good one!

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

Use `display: table;` Only add table and table-cell

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/75fff7vp/2/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Default Action
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

        //On Click Event
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
        });

    });
```

```css
.container {
    width: 1300;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

ul.tabs {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.tab_content h3 a {
    color: #254588;
}

.tab_content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Seville</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2"></a>Alicante</li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Córdoba</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">San Juan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab6">Havana</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 1</h2>
            <p> Content 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p> Content 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 3</h2>
            <p> Content 3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 4</h2>
            <p> Content 4</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 5</h2>
            <p> Content 5</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab6" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Heading 5</h2>
            <p> Content 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```